Access Azure DevOps Pipeline Artifacts from different organization
I am using the Azure DevOps pipeline task DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines
This task will download the artifacts of another pipeline. There's a parameter that allows for downloading artifacts from a pipeline in another project, but no such parameter exists for a pipeline in another organization. Is there a way to download artifacts from a pipeline in another org, assuming we can auth to that other org?

There is no available pipeline task can be used to download build artifacts from another Azure DevOps organization.
As a workaround, you can try to use the REST API to download the build artifacts from another Azure DevOps organization:

Call the API "Artifacts - Get Artifact" to get the downloadUrl of the specified build artifact.

Then call the downloadUrl to download the artifact as ZIP file.

Extract the ZIP file.



Below is the steps to configure the pipeline to call the API to download the build artifact:

Generate a PAT (Personal Access Token) in the Azure DevOps organization where you want to download the build artifact from. The PAT should have the "Build (Read)" scope at least.

In the pipeline where you want to download the artifact to, add the PAT generated above as a secret variable.


In the pipeline, you can use a PowerShell task to call the REST API to download the build artifact.


steps:
. . .

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Download Build Artifact'
  env:
    MY_PAT: $(myPAT)
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $organization = "xxx"
      $project = "xxx"
      $buildId = 3642
      $artifactName = "drop"
      $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/build/builds/${buildId}/artifacts?artifactName=${artifactName}&api-version=7.0"

      $pat = $env:MY_PAT
      $base64Token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
      $headers = @{Authorization = "Basic $base64Token"}

      $downloadUrl = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers $headers).resource.downloadUrl
      $zipFilePath="$PWD\drop.zip"
      Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $downloadUrl -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/zip" -OutFile $zipFilePath

      [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory( $zipFilePath, "$PWD")
      Remove-Item $zipFilePath



Thanks for the response, I appreciate it.

Another question: how do you know there's no pipeline task that supports cross-org artifact download for pipelines? Is there some documentation to confirm that for sure? Thanks

@Athanasius, There lists all the built-in Azure Pipelines tasks. I checked all the possible artifact download tasks, none of them can access artifact cross-org. I also went to the Marketplace to try searching whether there are any extensions can provide the pipeline tasks to access artifact cross-org, but also did not find any available extensions.

@Athanasius, I checked with pipelines resource and builds resource. They also are not available.
